# Best time complexity of a single loop?

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science

I have a really simple question, I have this loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    "some O(n) stuff here)"
}
```

what will be the BEST time complexity of this algorithm?
**O(n)?** *(for loop **O(1)** * **O(n)** stuff)*
or
**O(n^2)?** *(for loop **O(n)** * **O(n)** stuff inside the loop)*
Will the for loop itself be considered as O(n) as normally, or will it be considered as O(1)
since it will only make only 1 loop for the BEST case scenario?

Comment: " it will only make only 1 loop for the BEST case scenario?" lets say n = 5, then how can there be a "best case" with only 1 iteration?

Comment: @jarod42 so O(n^2) is the best, average, and worst case scenario time complexity of all three?

Comment: @ViliusBaranauskas In terms of big O, yes, even if you can perform O(k) work inside a loop, its still O(n*k), or more general O(n^2), always. The only thing that matters is function growth, that's what we are analyzing here with this. We aren't interested in real values, such as n = 5, k = 9. The performance impact of such is negligible, and unimportant, the compiler would probably just unroll this and leave us with a, technically, O(1), which I'm not sure is even correct to say because that's not what big O is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the best time complexity is O(N) (and even Θ(N)), if the best running time of "stuff" is constant (even zero).

Anyway, if "stuff" is known to be best case Ω(f(N)), then the best total time is  Ω(N f(N)).

Answer (score 0):

If your loop is doing `O(n)` stuff for `n` times then the time complexity will be `O(n^2)`. May you call it worst case. The best case and average case will be based on your `some O(n) stuff` that is executed with every iteration of your loop.

Lets take a simple example of bubble sort algorithm:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                swap(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Time complexity this will always be `O(n^2)`, whether array is sorted (irrespective of order - ascending or descending) or not.

But this can be optimised by observing that the `n`<sup>th</sup> pass finds the `n`<sup>th</sup> largest element and puts it into its final place. So, the inner loop can avoid looking at the last `n − 1` items when running for the `n`<sup>th</sup> time:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                swap(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now the best case time complexity is `O(n)` i.e. when the array is sorted in ascending order (in context of above implementation). Average and worst case are still `O(n^2)`.

So, to identify the best case time complexity of your algorithm you have to show us the implementation of `some O(n) stuff` and if not implementation then at least show the algorithm that you are trying to implement.

Answer (score -1):

As you stated it, it's O(n^2).
'Cause You are doing n times a O(n) operation.

Comment: This is wrong because O(N) is only an upper bound, and the *best* case could be O(1).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think such statement is fallacious because that's not how we look at "best case", otherwise every single algorithm best case would be O(1) because not using it in the first place is best case scenario, which is a constant time operation, even if that means that no time is used for it.

Comment: @Kaihaku: No, "not using it" is not allowed. The simple statement `for (i= 0; i < N; i++) {}` is O(N) but never O(1). And it is not unusual to have real-world O(N) algorithms with an O(1) best case. (E.g. insertion in an array.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's my point. Otherwise you can make the same argument for `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}` You could argue that its `O(1)`. Best case may be "O(1)", whatever that means really, but best complexity for a for loop will always be `O(N)`, because its not `N = 5`, or `N = 42`, `N` is `N`, always, function, which is why best complexity for the asker's example is always `O(N^2)`, no less, no more.

Comment: @Kaihaku: still wrong. Your first loop is indisputably O(1) because it has no dependency on N. With the condition i < N, it is Θ(N). Performing N insertions at the end of an array is O(N), while the worst case of N insertions is O(N²).

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, that example is deliberately wrong. It is wrong to just see `N` as any real number, that's my whole point.

Comment: @Kaihaku: the notation O holds *for all* N > N*, where N* is a constant that depends on the algorithm. N is a variable. I gave an example of an algorithm that has a best case O(N) and worst case O(N²), because the inner loop has best case O(1) and worst case O(N). (I never said that N=1, if that's what you think !)